Using promise.all with .then
I want to use await Promise.all with axios so that the requests can be sent concurrently. I have a map with the key as an id, and the value as an url. I want to retain the output also in a similar map, the key would still be the id but the value would be the response (arraybuffer).
Following is what I got suggested by a LLM:
async function fetchImages(
  idUrlMap: Map<string, string>
): Promise<Map<string, ArrayBuffer>> {
  // Convert the map into an array of promises
  const promises = Array.from(idUrlMap.entries()).map(([id, url]) => {
    return axios
      .get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
      .then(response => ({ id, data: response.data }));
  });

  // Resolve all promises concurrently
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);

  // Convert the results back into a map
  const resultMap = new Map<string, ArrayBuffer>();
  results.forEach(({ id, data }) => {
    resultMap.set(id, data);
  });

  return resultMap;
}

What I'm wondering is -- we are doing axios.get().then() for each array element, which will resolve the promise as soon as it's ready. So the promises won't actually get aggregated and get resolved at Promise.all. Hence I won't achieve concurrency.
Is my understanding correct? Why/why not?

The key here is that PROMISES DO NOT "EXECUTE" LATER. Using Promise.all() in no shape or form influences execution. All promises are always only a notification mechanism for an ongoing asynchronous operation. One you have a promise, it means there is already an async operation happening. So Promise.all() doesn't "initiate" or "start" or "execute" it. It only waits for all of them to succeed or for one to fail. That's it.

Gotcha.
But doing axios.get().then() is equivalent to await axios.get() right?
Meaning, what the above code will be doing is to wait for each array element till the promise is resolved. So concurrency is killed. We don't want that

"axios.get().then() is equivalent to await axios.get() right" no. await will pause the execution of the function until the promise resolves. Then resumes with its value. It's a way to make async code look as if it's syncronouse since const a = 1; const b = await someAsyncFn(); const c = a + b; will process the declaration of a first, then the surrounding function is suspended until the declaration of b goes through, then the declaration of c is processed. someAsyncFn().then(x => x + 1) will not pause the surrounding function. Just continues with x + 1 after the promise resolves

Also, await doesn't mean nothing else runs. Just that the current function doesn't. So if you have const x = await getX(); const y = await getY(); in the same function, they'd be done one after another. Because the first await stops the function from reaching the next one. But the two statements can still run without waiting for one another when in different functions.

I would suggest you run the following code to see the behavior yourself:
async function fetchImages(idUrlMap) {
    // Convert the map into an array of promises
    const promises = Array.from(idUrlMap.entries()).map(([id, url]) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(id, 'Triggered timeout');
            resolve();
        }, 3000-id*1000)
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('In then for', id);
        return { id }
      })
    });
  
    // Resolve all promises concurrently
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log('Results finished', results);
}

fetchImages(Object.entries({'1': 'test1', '2': 'test2', '3': 'test3'}));

This is a simplified version of yours which uses setTimeout instead of axios, but the same principle applies. You'll notice that results ends up being an array of the value returned in your then callback. In other words, it all runs as you would expect, no overthinking required.
Expected output:
2 Triggered timeout
In then for 2
1 Triggered timeout
In then for 1
0 Triggered timeout
In then for 0
Results finished [ { id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 } ]


Got it, thanks for this!
I was actually thinking axios.get().then() would have same behavior as axios.get()
This is ofc not correct


So the promises won't actually get aggregated and get resolved at Promise.all:

This is true: all that Promise.all does is create a new promise whose resolution depends on the resolution of those individual promises.

Hence I won't achieve concurrency.

If by concurrency you refer to the HTTP requests, then they have all been launched with the synchronous calls of axios (there is no asynchronous delay between these calls), and any non-JavaScript logic that implements those requests and retrieval of responses, can in principle run concurrently. Note that no JavaScript code in your snippet will run concurrently. It just finishes the function once it executes the first await it encounters (returning a promise), and then the JS engine will just monitor its queues and execute then callbacks as promises resolve. The last one to resolve is the promise returned by Promise.all. And then the fetchImages function can resume and execute its return statement. That will resolve the promise that the caller of fetchImages had received earlier on.
Some comments on the code

You don't need to call .entries() on a map to iterate it, as the map itself is iterable.
You don't need to first create an array with Array.from and then chain a map on it. Instead, use the second argument of Array.from which can perform the mapping.
If you turn the individual responses in key/value pairs (arrays) instead of little plain objects, you can feed the resulting array directly to the Map constructor, and avoid the loop at the end.

Adapted code:
async function fetchImages(idUrlMap: Map<string, string>): Promise<Map<string, ArrayBuffer>> {
  // No need to call .entries(). You can use the second argument of Array.from:
  const promises = Array.from(idUrlMap, ([id, url]) => {
    return axios
      .get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
      // Map the response to key/value pairs
      .then(response => [id, response.data]);
  });

  // Promise.all does not resolve the promises. It merely creates a new 
  //  promise that will resolve when all the given promises have resolved.
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);

  // Use the Map constructor argument to create the Map:
  return new Map<string, ArrayBuffer>(results);
}


Got it, thanks for your explanation!
